# How can I access a google cloud datastore using graphql?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, graphql-js

As of now we are using gstore to query the google cloud datastore, but we're looking to migrate from REST to GraphQL. The problem is I can't find any resources online on how to access the data on the google cloud datastore using GraphQL. I've got GraphQL working with local json files but haven't been able to make it query from the datastore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [graphql-genie](https://github.com/genie-team/graphql-genie) supports GraphQL on Cloud Datastore.  If that doesn't work for you, should should be able to adapt the Firestore with GraphQL code.